# How to open the current directory in Git bash

Tags: bash, git, pycharm, git-bash

Context: I am a total command line noob. I am following this tutorial to get started on Git: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QqP7YZlZEOo. I am a windows user.

I have just installed Git and added PyCharm as my default text editor. I then opened the "Git Bash" at the end of installation. I successfully made the new directory  "git-work-flow", just as he did in the video. I then used "cd" to move to the new folder. Where I lose him is when he opens the new directory in his default text editor, Sublime.

I cannot find the corresponding command to open it with my default editor, PyCharm.

PyCharm [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/opening-files-from-command-line.html) says use "PyCharm .", but this does not work. Neither does 'pycharm64 .' or any other combination or permutation of answers shotgunned all over this site. Some have mentioned some extra set-up required but no documentation is found that I can follow, being a total noob.

How can I do this?

Comment: are you able open PyCharm from `cmd`? If not try adding `pycharm path to your environment variable. http://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/working-with-the-ide-features-from-command-line.html

Comment: @Poojan Added the "path variable" and restarted Git and it works with 'pycharm64 .' multiple protests of illegal reflective access and recommendation to report the errors. Should I worry?

Answer (score 1):

One interpretation of the question title is "What is (or how to find) the current directory in git bash?". Linux syntax is likely to be unfamiliar to long-time Windows users, so you may be interested in the command:

```
$ explorer .
```

This opens Windows Explorer pointing to the current directory (i.e. wherever you happen to be in `bash`).

Answer (score 0):

The "." at the end means "current directory" so you just have to have a program which accepts paths as parameter, e.g. pycharm.
If it doesn't work it means probably it's not in the path, as Poojan suggested, so either one can:

- type the full path to the executable for it, e.g. something like (double quotes actually necessary because of space in path)

  "c:\program files\pycharm\bin\pycharm64" .
- or put the path in the PATH environment variable, e.g.

  - Startmenu->run->SystemPropertiesAdvanced
  - Environment variables
  - double click PATH
  - add the path, e.g. c:\program files\pycharm\bin\pycharm64